# jQuery remove element on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `<button>` with ajax on it, and want to remove it after successful request.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".approve").click(function(){
        var el, image_id =  $(this).data('image-id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "PATCH",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "approved": "True"},
            url: "/ml/api/image/" + image_id + "/?format=json",
            success: function(data){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But this doesn't work…

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The context in the success callback is different from the context of the click event meaning `this` no longer refers to the button DOM element. Just select the button again and it would remove it:

```
$(".approve").click(function(){
    var el = $(this), image_id =  $(this).data('image-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "PATCH",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "approved": "True"},
        url: "/ml/api/image/" + image_id + "/?format=json",
        success: function(data){
            el.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! :) _It's so not cool to be backend-only dev, huh_

Comment: is there a way just to remove the Close button?

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to pass `context` property to ajax:

```
$(".approve").click(function(){
    var image_id =  $(this).data('image-id');
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        type: "PATCH",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "approved": "True"},
        url: "/ml/api/image/" + image_id + "/?format=json",
        success: function(data){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my methode. Easy.

```
var element = $(this);

 $.ajax({
     success: function(){          
          element.remove();     
     }
});
```