# jQuery - Remove some elements from AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

AJAX response:

```
<div id="div_1">Some text</div>
<div id="div_2">Some text</div>
<div id="div_3">Some text</div>
```

Now I need to remove some divse, before the result is shown to users. So lets for example remove div_1 and div_3:

```
var result = $(ajax_response).find('#div_1, #div_3').remove();
```

Now we can show it to users:

```
$('#result_div').html(result);
```

**But it doesn't work - nothing will show up**. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Working solution, but I don't like, that I have to show the result before a change it:

```
 $('#result_div').html(ajax_response).find('#div_1, #div_3').remove();
```

Comment: So all three DIVs are still showing?

Comment: The ajax response are not jquery elements yet, the result comes in a string and you append to your html right?

Comment: I solved it by this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546749/jquery-remove-element-on-ajax-success

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find()` only works within the context of an element. The three elements you receive are all siblings, so you can either wrap them in a container on the server side:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="div_1">Some text</div>
    <div id="div_2">Some text</div>
    <div id="div_3">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Or you can do that programmatically in your JS:

```
var $container = $(ajax_response).wrap('<div />').parent();
$container.find('#div_1, #div_3').remove();
$('#result_div').html($container);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T8BpJ/3/)

Comment: This will not work, because variable "result" will be empty: http://jsfiddle.net/T8BpJ/2/

Comment: @KoralekM. very good point. Not sure how I missed that. Answer amended: http://jsfiddle.net/T8BpJ/3/